# Google Apps Script - I am unable to retrieve user's email address when add-on is published

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, add-on

The following code works before I publish the G docs add-on. However the released version obtained via Google Docs Add-on/my_add-on doesn't work.

What concepts am I missing here?

```js
onOpen(){

  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) explicitly states that:

> If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity,
>   User.getEmail() returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the
>   email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address
>   is not available in any context that allows a script to run without
>   that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e)
>   trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to
>   "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the
>   user). However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the
>   developer and the user belong to the same Google Apps for Business
>   domain.

So presumably your script fails to meet those conditions.
You need to run a function that the user has to authorize first in order to get their email.

Comment: Thanks, Robin.   I read up on Authorization to learn how to such code needs to be written/executed.   ...If you have any recommendations before I begin, I'd be interested as I have not dove into this topic before.

Comment: That depends on your use case. The easiest solution is to add a button to your menu to do the authorization process.

Comment: Will that be a one-time click for the user or would the user need to click that button every time that function was accessed?

Comment: I ask because initially installing the add-on, the user Accepts "Get Users Email".  I see where my code has an issue with onOpen(); however, the other location where getEmail is used is also blocked.  Can you see how this is confusing?  The user initially Accepts that the email address can be accessed yet I need to have them authorize again to access the email address.

Comment: It should be a one time click. Once they authorized an action on a spreadsheet it does not need to be authorized for that spreadsheet anymore.